# Android Notification SetAutoCancel not working

Tags: android, notifications

I have a notification that I would like to close on button click. I use SetAutoCancel but it doesnt work. Anyone got a clue how to achieve it? Using this button `remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notificationbutton, pIntent);`

Codes

```
RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
                R.layout.customnotification);

        String strtitle = getString(R.string.customnotificationtitle);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationView.class);

        intent.putExtra("text", strtext);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notificationbutton, pIntent);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logosmall)
                .setTicker(getString(R.string.customnotificationticker))
                .setAutoCancel(true).setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .setContent(remoteViews);

        remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.imagenotileft,
                R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.title,
                getString(R.string.customnotificationtitle));
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.text,
                getString(R.string.customnotificationtext));

        NotificationManager notificationmanager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationmanager.notify(0, builder.build());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

autoCancel works only if default notification click is invoked if you are using buttons you have to clear notifications your self

off topic why using custom buttons when there is builder.addAction ?

Comment: yeah, I know about the addAction. I want to try out a custom button. How do you clear the notification?

Comment: call clear(int id) on your NotificationManager instance in your case id is 0

Comment: The method clear(int) is undefined for the type NotificationManager. Cant do that I guess

Comment: sorry i ment cancel(int) :)